# ToggleSwitch not worked in windowsphone7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, togglebutton, assemblyfileversion

I used ToggleSwitch control in windowsphone, It works fine in windowsphone7 version, takes Microsoft.Phone.Controls as a assembly reference. But in the windowsphone7.5 it asks assembly reference for ToggleSwitch control, it's not included in Microsoft.Phone.Controls. Anyone know the assembly reference for windowsphone7.5 ToggleSwitch control.

Comment: Isn't `ToggleSwitch` part of the `Silverlight Toolkit`? Can you provide a link to the MSDN page of your control (it should have the assembly there as well anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToggleSwitch control is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), and is part of the namespace  `Microsoft.Phone.Controls`.

To enable it in your project, add a reference to the toolkit dll (or better yet, use NuGet to install it), and then reference the namespace in your XAML

*(I'm sure you already know this stuff, and that the actual alias you choose isn't important as long as you use the same one when adding the control to the XAML - using "toolkit" here because that's what I normally do)*

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and make sure your declaration of the control in the XAML includes the namespace reference...

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch ... ><!-- more stuff here --></toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```